# Highchart datepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I am trying to get jquery-ui datepicker to work with highcharts so that a user can select a date an example being

A user selects 10th October  to 25th October

Once the user has selected the dates the highchart should redraw and show the hours for the projects that have done along with the tasks. My chart looks like the following:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VmxZ.png)

From the photo currently the highchart shows the hours a user has done for a task against the project “Asda”.

At the moment I have the chart simply displays the hours for the current week. What I am trying to do is use the jquery datepicker so that it can display past hours that the user has entered. If the user selects “from 10th October” “to “25th October” the chart should redraw and show the hours and projects for the selected date range.

My code follows:

**Index.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts', 'exporting' %>

<%= render 'projectselect' %>

<div class = 'right'>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="15"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" size="15"/>
</div>

<button id="button">Redraw</button>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);});
onchange: $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });

$('#button').click(function() {
    chart.redraw();
});

var options = {
    chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         defaultSeriesType: 'column'
      },
      title: {
          text: '<%= current_user.username %>',
      },
      subtitle: {
         text: 'Project Hours'
      },
      xAxis: {
         categories: [
            'Pre-Sales',
            'Project',
            'Fault Fixing',
            'Support',
            'Out Of Hours',
            'Sick',
            'Toil',
            'Leave'  
         ]
      },
      yAxis: {
         min: 0,
         title: {
            text: 'Hours'
         }
      },
        plotOptions: {
         series: {
            stacking: 'normal'

         }
      },ip: {
         formatter: function() {
            return ''+
               this.x +': '+ this.y +' Hours';
         }
      },

      credits: {
         text: '',
         href: ''
      },

      exporting: {
         enabled: true,
         filename: 'Project-Hours'
      },

      plotOptions: {
         column: {
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            borderWidth: 0
         }
      },

      series: [
      <% @users_projects.each do |users_project| %>
                <% if !users_project.user.nil? && current_user.full_name == users_project.user.full_name %>
                  <% @data.each do |data| %>
            <% if data[ :values ] == [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] %>
            <% else %>
              <% if data[ :name ] == users_project.project.project_name %>
              {
                name: '<%= data[ :name ] %>',
                data: [
                <% data[ :values ].each do |value| %>
                 <%= value %>,
                <% end %>
                ]
              },
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
                <% end %>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
            <% end %>
      ]
};
</script>
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: would have been great if you have shared a fiddle of you code

Comment: @Rinzler I can give you a gist for the code that I ended up with

Comment: ya sure i would like to see how a date picker would work with a highcharts . will u create a fiddle or answer your question.

Comment: @Rinzler my question had alread been answered. But here my gist code - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5364520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onSelect` callback of datepickers, you should validate, if both `#from` and `#to` are selected (or provide sensible defaults if not) and at the end fire and xhr request to server to get new series of data.

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
  var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
  instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
      instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
      selectedDate,
      instance.settings
    );
    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );

    // validate if we have both dates and get new series from server
    if ($(dates[0]).datepicker("getDate") &&
        $(dates[1]).datepicker("getDate")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= user_projects_path(params[:user_id]) %>',
        data: {"from": $(dates[0]).datepicker("getDate"), "to" : $(dates[1]).datepicker("getDate") },
        success: function(data) {
          // now we have new series of data to display in graph
          // we remove the old one, add the new and redraw the chart
          for(var i=0; i<chart.series.length; i++) {
            chart.get(chart.series[i].options.id).remove();
          }

          // fiddle with json data from xhr response to form valid series
          var series = data; 
          chart.addSeries(series, true); // second param says we want to redraw chart
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Controller method under `user_projects_path` url needs to exists and return JSON formatted series data for given `user_id` of course. You can filter your series data before returning with params sent by jquery xhr request (`from` and `to`).

Quick and dirty solution but I hope you got the point...

Comment: So you saying that I need to right a method in my statistics controller that takes the data in an array and converts into JSON?

Comment: Not exactly - you need to write a controller method, which returns users projects hours data filtered by params from AJAX request (`from` and `to`) as json array - your new series. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Is there not a possible way I could do this without making an ajax request and using the chart.redraw(); method?

Comment: I believe there isn't - when you change the period (`from` and `to`) to display, you have to fetch this period from server. The second parameter of `chart.addSeries(series, true)` in fact causes the chart to redraw with the new series.

Comment: Well, in fact, there is a way to do this without request to server - you could render all users project hours data for, say, a year ago and then filter them only in JS, but what forces you to do it JS-only?