# highcharts year interval with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

```
<?php 
  for ($i= 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
if ( $i <= 9)  { 
$month = '0' . $i;
} else {
$month = $i; 
}
 $date = date('d');
$year = date("Y");
//  $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.$i.'-'.date('d')));
$month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date."-" . $i ."-". $year));  
$where = array('date_saved >=' => $year . "-" . '0' . $i . '-' . '01',   'date_saved <=' => $year . "-" . '0' . $i . '-' . '31');
$invoice[$i] = count($this->db->where($where)->get('tbl_invoices')-  result());

} var_dump( $invoice);

?>
```

I have the above code which give result as below for current year start from Jan to Dec(xAxis):

```
array(12) { [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(0) [9]=> int(0) [10]=> int(1) [11]=> int(3) [12]=> int(0) }
```

How do i place a `datepicker` inside `highcharts` to select yearly basic?

I have been trying the below function but I realize this is not going to work since my result in `(int)` with current year option `($year = date("Y");)`. 
Any suggestion in order for me to have the yearly basic datepicker option?

```
   $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat:  " ",
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>asset/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('admin/chart/data');?>",  function(json){

           options.series.push(json[1]);
           options.series.push(json[2]);
            options.series.push(json[3]);
            options.series.push(json[4]);
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611406/highchart-datepicker

Comment: I don't understand, why the C++ tag?  I don't see any C++ code or any verbage related to C++.